# using grid.SetCellAlignment in python

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a grid in wxpython and I want to show all text in center of cells.

From what I can tell this is doable with

`grid.SetCellAlignment(0, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)`

However as you can see this is local property of cell. How can I do that for the whole grid?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [StaticText](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/StaticText.html) class to align the text rather than using SetCellAlignment.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an inherited class from wx.grid.Grid, and add a method called SetGridAlignment.  Something like the following:

```
import wx
import wx.grid as wxgrid

class Grid(wxgrid.Grid):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        wxgrid.Grid.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

    def SetGridAlignment(self,halign,valign):
        """
        This method aligns all cells of the grid.

        halign :   Horizontal alignment
        valign :   Vertical alignment
        """
        nrows=self.GetNumberRows()
        ncols=self.GetNumberCols()
        for ii in range(nrows):
            for jj in range(ncols):
                self.SetCellAlignment(ii,jj,halign,valign)


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, u"Simple Grid", size=(300,200))
    gr = Grid(frame, -1)
    gr.CreateGrid(10,2)
    gr.SetGridAlignment(wx.ALIGN_CENTRE,wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grid.SetDefaultCellAlignment(wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.